# Cannot change Sharing on Account for Customer Portal Users

Tags: sharing, experience-cloud, user-management

Using the 'Share' button on an Account I have provided Account Access to particular users. When I want to edit the access to Partner or Customer Portal Users this option is grayed out.

I tried all kinds of things such as changing profile, enabling/disabling users, removing them from Experience Cloud Members but with no success.

As you can see on the screenshot this can be adjusted for normal type of Users.

Am I missing something or is it not possible and the only option is to create new users?

[image]